# oracle composite primary key vs index

Tags: oracle, performance, composite-primary-key

I'm designing a table which I has a multiple foreign keys. What I did is create an extra column for primary key which will work more as a correlative, but I could also make the foreign keys as a composite primary key.
 So my question is about performance: Is it better (at least for Oracle) to have a composite primary key than a index? What is better for my case?
Thanks!

Comment: Better for what ? inserts ? queries using the compound key ? queries based on a _part_ of the compound key ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I clarify, better for Select queries based on the foreign keys columns, relatively small amount of data

Answer (score 1):

As @Sylvain_Leroux points out, the term "better" is actually very ambiguous depending on your goals because there are tradeoffs to both approaches.

#### Ensure Composite Key is Actually Unique

First of all, if you want to use a composite primary key out of the foreign keys, then you must be sure that the combination of the foreign keys will be truly unique for each record. Otherwise, of course, you won't be able to use them as a primary key. If instead you are describing using a composite key made up of the foreign keys plus a surrogate key, that's kind of the worst of both worlds and is generally frowned upon.

#### ETL Back Room Considerations

The choice you are considering is a common one in OLAP, where a designer must choose whether or not to use a surrogate key for the fact table or a composite key comprised of the keys of the dimension tables. This advice from page 487 of Ralph Kimball's *The Data Warehouse Toolkit Third Edition* would therefore apply to your situation (you can consider your table as being analogous to what he describes as a fact table, and the foreign keys are for tables that he refers to as dimensions):

> Fact table surrogate keys have a number of uses in the ETL back room. First, as previously described, they can be used as the basis for backing out or resuming an interrupted load. Second, they provide immediate and unambiguous identification of a single fact row without needing to constrain multiple dimensions to fetch a unique row. Third, updates to fact table rows can be replaced by inserts plus deletes because the fact table surrogate key is now the actual key for the fact table. Thus, a row containing updated columns can now be inserted into the fact table without overwriting the row it is to replace. When all such insertions are complete, then the underlying old rows can be deleted in a single step. Fourth, the fact table surrogate key is an ideal parent key to be used in a parent/child design. The fact table surrogate key appears as a foreign key in the child, along with the parent's dimension foreign key.

#### Performance Considerations

From a performance perspective, the records are stored in order by primary key(s) physically on the disk. That makes reads based on queries that use a foreign key (or keys) for lookup faster, but also could mean that writes will be slower if they require inserting records at points other than at the end. This is because the DBMS will have to physically move the records to make room (this is slightly oversimplified because there are some schemes employed by the DBMS to combat this, but they are overwhelmed if the inserts are numerous enough).

If you were to use a surrogate key, the insert problem wouldn't be an issue, but of course in situations where you are looking up by foreign keys, you wouldn't get the advantage of having your data in order physically on the disk. Assuming you would put an index on each foreign key, then that would add some overhead to insert tasks because the DBMS has to update multiple indices.

All of this is only noticeable with large amounts of data and will not make much of a difference for a relatively small amount of data.